# USB - autorun a web address

Tags: usb, shellexecute, autorun

I currently have 2 files on it:

```
autorun.inf
start.url
```

autorun.inf contains 3 lines:

```
[autorun]  
ShellExecute=start.url
open=start.url
```

start.url contains 5 lines:

```
[InternetShortcut]
URL=http://cnn.com
IDList=
[{000214A0-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}]
Prop3=19,2
```

Loads ok on Vista, but does not load on XP or Windows7.

Any clue what to change?

Comment: OP Reposted to SuperUser - http://superuser.com/questions/221889/usb-autorun-a-web-address

Answer (score 0):

Is the autorun functionality disabled on the XP and Win7 boxes? If so you have to re-enable it.

See this article for how it was, probably, disabled in XP: [How to disable the Autorun functionality in Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/967715)

Though I think it could also have been disabled in a group policy.

Comment: The functionality was not disabled. Any other clues?

Comment: @Lavi: Since it works in Vista, but not on XP or 7, it's almost certainly some kind of configuration issue (if it worked only on XP, maybe it was a security issue and if it worked only on 7 maybe it was new functionality, but if it only works on the one in the middle it's probably not due to the version as such). I'd suggest asking on the superuser site instead, since you might get better answers there.

Comment: Thanks, I've posted it there now.